# Windows 11 right side of taskbar not working

Tags: windows, taskbar, windows-11

I got a new computer with Windows 10.
I directly updated it to Windows 11.
I noticed that the icons on right side of the taskbar are not clickable. For example , if I click on the Wifi or sound icon nothing is showed. Same for the time/date.
I tried reinstalling the nvidia display drivers but same issue.
Any ideas on how to fix this ?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting?

Comment: The sound/wifi icon should pop up a shade from the side of the screen similar to the toggles that were at the bottom of the Windows 10 notification area and the date should show a calendar and notifications. As David says the first thing would be a reboot, otherwise this sounds like a problem with Explorer. Do you have any taskbar customisation apps installed?

Comment: Yes , I already tried multiple reboot. I don't have any taskbar customization.

Comment: Try doing a Windows 11 Repair Install. ....  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11   ...  I have used this approach and it works.

Comment: There are still unresolved issues in Windows 11. If you've "upgraded" within ten days, it should be relatively simple to revert to working Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find anyway to fix the problem.
Reinstalling windows fixed it.
Thanks